# sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedShuffleSplit - error: "indices are out-of-bounds"

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I was trying to split the sample dataset using Scikit-learn's Stratified Shuffle Split. I followed the example shown on the Scikit-learn documentation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# UCI's wine dataset
wine = pd.read_csv("https://s3.amazonaws.com/demo-datasets/wine.csv")

# separate target variable from dataset
target = wine['quality']
data = wine.drop('quality',axis = 1)

# Stratified Split of train and test data
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedShuffleSplit
sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(target, n_iter=3, test_size=0.2)

for train_index, test_index in sss:
    xtrain, xtest = data[train_index], data[test_index]
    ytrain, ytest = target[train_index], target[test_index]

# Check target series for distribution of classes
ytrain.value_counts()
ytest.value_counts()
```

However, upon running this script, I get the following error:

```
IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds
```

Could someone please point out what I am doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like your index error should occur here: `xtrain, xtest = data[train_index], data[test_index]`.  If so can you edit your question to help others locate the problem.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You're running into the different conventions for Pandas `DataFrame` indexing versus NumPy `ndarray` indexing.  The arrays `train_index` and `test_index` are collections of row indices.  But `data` is a Pandas `DataFrame` object, and when you use a single index into that object, as in `data[train_index]`, Pandas is expecting `train_index` to contain *column* labels rather than row indices.  You can either convert the dataframe to a NumPy array, using `.values`:

```
data_array = data.values
for train_index, test_index in sss:
    xtrain, xtest = data_array[train_index], data_array[test_index]
    ytrain, ytest = target[train_index], target[test_index]
```

or use the Pandas [`.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-position) accessor:

```
for train_index, test_index in sss:
    xtrain, xtest = data.iloc[train_index], data.iloc[test_index]
    ytrain, ytest = target[train_index], target[test_index]
```

I tend to favour the second approach, since it gives `xtrain` and `xtest` of type `DataFrame` rather than `ndarray`, and so keeps the column labels.

Comment: Thank you Mark, the `.iloc` accessor work perfectly.

Comment: With Pandas 0.17.1 and Scikit Learn 0.17.0, this does not work. The following gives the same error as the OP posted: `grid = GridSearchCV(decision_tree, param_grid={'max_depth':np.arange(1,3)}, cv=sss, scoring='roc_auc')`
`grid.fit(xtrain,ytrain)`.

Comment: @WR: That looks like a different issue to me; you may want to post a new question.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Done. It should have a dedicated question.

Comment: this is applicable for `timeseriessplit` too

Comment: can you use .loc instead of .iloc? I tried both and they give me same results, why?

Comment: @Roman: Smells like a new question to me, but what does the index look like for the DataFrame you were using? If the index is a simple range index, then yes, `.loc` and `.iloc` would be equivalent.