# sklearn grid.fit(X,y) - error: “positional indexers are out-of-bounds” for X_train,y_train

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search

This is a question about scikit learn (version 0.17.0) in Python 2.7 along with Pandas 0.17.1. In order to split raw data (with no missing entries) using the approach detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30023927/sklearn-cross-validation-stratifiedshufflesplit-error-indices-are-out-of-bou/30025025?noredirect=1#comment59645227_30025025), I have found that if the split data are used to proceed with a `.fit()` that there is an error that appears.

Here is the code taken largely unchanged from the other stackoverflow question with renaming of variables. I have then instantiated a grid and tried to fit the split data with the aim of determining optimal classifier parameters. The error occurs after the last line of the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# UCI's wine dataset
wine = pd.read_csv("https://s3.amazonaws.com/demo-datasets/wine.csv")

# separate target variable from dataset
y = wine['quality']
X = wine.drop(['quality','color'],axis = 1)

# Stratified Split of train and test data
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedShuffleSplit
sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(y, n_iter=3, test_size=0.2)

# Split dataset to obtain indices for train and test set
for train_index, test_index in sss:
    xtrain, xtest = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
    ytrain, ytest = y[train_index], y[test_index]

# Pick some classifier here
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
decision_tree = DecisionTreeClassifier()

from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
# Instantiate grid
grid = GridSearchCV(decision_tree, param_grid={'max_depth':np.arange(1,3)}, cv=sss, scoring='accuracy')

# this line causes the error message
grid.fit(xtrain,ytrain)
```

**Here is the error message produced by the above code:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\test.py", line 23, in <module>
    grid.fit(xtrain,ytrain)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\grid_search.py", line 804, in fit
    return self._fit(X, y, ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\grid_search.py", line 553, in _fit
    for parameters in parameter_iterable
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 800, in __call__
    while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 658, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 566, in _dispatch
    job = ImmediateComputeBatch(batch)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 180, in __init__
    self.results = batch()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 72, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py", line 1524, in _fit_and_score
    X_train, y_train = _safe_split(estimator, X, y, train)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py", line 1591, in _safe_split
    X_subset = safe_indexing(X, indices)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 152, in safe_indexing
    return X.iloc[indices]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1227, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(key, axis=0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1504, in _getitem_axis
    self._is_valid_list_like(key, axis)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1443, in _is_valid_list_like
    raise IndexError("positional indexers are out-of-bounds")
IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds
```

**NOTE:**
It is important to me to keep `X` and `y` as Pandas datastructures, similar to the second approach presented in the other stackoverflow question above. i.e. I would not want to use `X.values` and `y.values`.

**Question:**
Using the raw data as a Pandas datastructure (`DataFrame` for `X` and `Series` for `y`), is there a way to run `grid.fit()` without getting this error message?

Comment: One issue in this script is that the CV object sss is producing indices for all of the rows in y.  When you're calling grid.fit - you're giving it only xtrain, ytrain, which are shorter than y, therefore position indexers are out-of-bounds.  Once you create sss you do not need to split the dataframes.  Pass whole X and y into grid.fit and it does the splitting according to the indices from sss.

Comment: That's right, but I am also giving it `y_test`. The size of `X_test` matches that of `y_test`. Shouldn't this mean that position indexers match?

Comment: @WR, no, you are giving `y` to the `StratifiedShuffleSplit` and `xtrain, ytrain` to `grid.fit`. This is the root of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass `X` and `y` directly to `fit()`, like

```
grid.fit(X, y)
```

and `GridSearchCV` will take care of

```
xtrain, xtest = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
ytrain, ytest = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

---

The `StratifiedShuffleSplit` instance, when iterated over, yields pairs of train/test split **indices**:

```
>>> list(sss)
[(array([2531, 4996, 4998, ..., 3205, 2717, 4983]), array([5942,  893, 1702, ..., 6340, 4806, 2537])),
 (array([1888, 2332, 6276, ..., 1674,  775, 3705]), array([3404, 3304, 4741, ..., 4397, 3646, 1410])),
 (array([1517, 3759, 4402, ..., 5098, 4619, 4521]), array([1110, 4076, 1280, ..., 6384, 1294, 1132]))]
```

`GridSearchCV` will use these indices to split the training samples. There is no need for you to do it manually.

The error occurs because you are feeding `xtrain` and `ytrain` (one of the train/test splits) into the cross-validator. The cross-validator tries to access items which exist in the full dataset but not in the train/test split, which raises an `IndexError`.

Comment: But then how does one create a hold out set? Without splitting, there is no way to get `x_test`, `y_test`. Or is there another method to create a hold out dataset for `X` and `y`?

Comment: Cross validation implies iterating through a number of train/test splits (in your case, 3), and averaging the score. `GridSearchCV` automatically does this. Why do you need another hold-out set?

Comment: If you really want to hold out a chunk of data, you can use something like `train_test_split`, which just produces a single split of the data (rather than an iterable of splits). In the end, you need to make sure to instantiate `StratifiedShuffleSplit` with the `y` which comes from the `X, y` tuple which you are passing to `fit(...)`.

Comment: Okay, the `train_test_split` part is making sense to me - use `train_test_split()` to create a testing (i.e. hold out) set and use the training set in `grid.fit()` as `grid.fit(X_train,y_train)`. Does that follow the correct rationale for using a hold out set?

Comment: What you described will work if you **also** do `StratifiedShuffleSplit(y_train, ...)`. My question is, what do you plan to do with `X_test, y_test`?

Comment: Wouldn't you train the classifier with `X_train`, `y_train` and then evaluate the classifier using `X_test`, `y_test`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106301/discussion-between-igor-raush-and-w-r).